# Why log out not working properly in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using AngulaJS as font-end and Sprint Boot as back-end. Here i am working with REST API. To build a log out service i have  followed the following tutorials but it is not working.

[URL-based authorization](https://kielczewski.eu/2014/12/spring-boot-security-application/)

[Spring Security logout does not work - does not clear security context and authenticated user still exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557294/spring-security-logout-does-not-work-does-not-clear-security-context-and-authe)

I have also seen some other web pages, based on these tutorials i have build the following code. But it is not working. I have 4 browsers. IE, Microsoft Edge, Firefox and Chrome. Most of the time i use Google Chrome. The problem is happening for Google Chrome most of the time.
I am using Net-Beans IDE, with Tomcat server.

I also have tried by simple "session.invalidate();"

```
     @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/topics","/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/topics")
//                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
//                .deleteCookies("remember-me")
                .deleteCookies()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);

    }
```

When entering log out url then the "logoutSuccessUrl("/topics")" is working, it is returning data.

Here i have tried all of  these 3 "deleteCookies()" methods.

I also tried "Proggrammatically logout" as one of the tutorials has mentioned.(second link)

**Proggrammatically logout**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/logout"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String logoutDo(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
         session= request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        for(Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        }

    return "logout";
}
```

Comment: Logout and basic authentication don't work together. Basic auth always sends the login information in the headers. So even if you logout, on the next request you login again. This is not a limitation of Spring Security but how http basic auth works. You should also clear the headers in your angular application after logging out.

Comment: @M. Deinum wolud u tell me how can i solve it

Comment: I already told you that... You need to clear the headers in your javascript client. If you rely on your browser there is nothing you can do about it.