# Spring security: Delete cookie for logout

Tags: java, spring

I use the following security configuration for my Spring boot app:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("auth_code").invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
        // We filter the api/signup requests
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTSignupFilter("/signup", authenticationManager(),
                    accountRepository, passwordEncoder),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // We filter the api/login requests
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in
        // header
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

When I do the logout, I want to delete the cookie which was set during the login. I use `deleteCookie`, but in the header there's no notion of deleting the cookie which was set during the login. Why ?

How should I tell the browser to delete the cookie ?

Right now, the header for the response contains :

```
Set-Cookie →JSESSIONID=E4060381B435217F7D68EAAE82903BB0;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
```

Should I set the expiration time for the cookie to a date past the current date ?

Comment: FYI you could look into `Clear Site Data` header, you might find this answer useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949089/1225551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to delete the cookie. Once the session has closed on the server, the cookie can't be used anyway, and it will be replaced if the person returns. Just let it expire normally (by default, when the browser is closed).

Comment: How is the `JSESSIONID` used on the client side ? should the client explicitly include it in the header for each request ?

Comment: Cookies are automatically sent as headers in the request.

Comment: @ThrawnCA There are sometimes good reason to delete the session cookie.  For example, if a load balancer is looking at that cookie to route you to a consistent server on the backend, you may want the user to be assigned a new server when they log out and back in again.  Such is the case in Blue-Green Deployment - once you've deployed a new version, you would want the user to be routed to a new server with the new software if they explicitly log out and back in again.

Comment: To be more clear: although you get a new cookie when you log in, if you don't delete the cookie on logout, then the login request will still have the old cookie which will cause the client to get routed to the old server.

Answer (score 3):

Add `JSESSIONID` in the `.deleteCookies("auth_code", "JSESSIONID")`.

```
logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("auth_code", "JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear on my question. I don't want to unset JSESSIONID. I don't care about it. I want to delete the cookie for the `auth_code`. To delete a cookie from the server side, do I have to set its expiration time to some time in the past and set it again ? or deleteCookies is good enough ? There's nothing on the header that tells the browser to delete the cookie.

Comment: Yes that is enough. When you set the cookie name in `deleteCookies` that cookie will be set a maxAge of 0 by the CookieClearingLogoutHandler in the response header http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/CookieClearingLogoutHandler.java

Comment: in my app I have
`.logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "JWT").logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html") .clearAuthentication(true).invalidateHttpSession(true)`
redirect to successUrl is going but cookies are not erased ... what might be the reason?

Comment: did you find fix for this issue? am facing same issue unable to delete cookies at sever side.  first time after logout url is redirect to login page asking for user password. next time it is not redirecting to login page and loaded home page without user password.

Comment: I am also experiencing the issue that Andrey and Muralidhar are having and would much appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There can be different approaches to delete the cookies using spring security:

1. You may add the following methods with logout in the spring security configure method.

   `.logout()`

delete cookies method to delete the list of cookies separated by comma(,)

```
`.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","remember-me")`
```

Clear all authentication

```
`.clearAuthentication(true)`
```

and then invalidate the session object.

```
`.invalidateHttpSession(true)`
```

2. Expire and remove the cookies explicitly and map that with `/logout` path.

   `@RequestMapping(path = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

`private void removeCookies(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {`

```
 Cookie rememberMeCookie = new Cookie("remember-me", "");

 rememberMeCookie.setMaxAge(0);

 response.addCookie(rememberMeCookie);

 securityService.logoutCurrentUser();
    }
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-servlet-cookies-session