# Oauth2 SpringBoot logout issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Below config code is not working for logout. I am still able to access the restricted urls after logout.

@Autowired
ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

```
OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
    OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler successHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
    //successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(URI.create("http://localhost:8081/"));
    successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}");
    return successHandler;
}
```

@Override

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/","/error").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated() 
    .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
        .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)     .clearAuthentication(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .and().oauth2Login()
    .redirectionEndpoint()
    .baseUri("/api/v1/oauth/callback");             
}
```

Comment: @JoeGrandja,@MichalTrojanowski Could you please help on this issue?

Comment: The configuration looks alright, though I'm thinking that most of the logout configuration is probably unnecessary. Perhaps there is some other part of the application that is contributing to the issue. Using Spring Security's DEBUG logging may reveal some additional detail. Either way. you might consider simplifying your DSL to this: https://gist.github.com/jzheaux/a282fecc364adf64d70a11568e5a2b44

Comment: @jzheaux When I delete all the cookies manually then logout happens

Comment: That makes sense since one of those cookies is JSESSIONID. Do you see the cookie getting removed in the logout HTTP response?

Comment: @jzheaux I have one more issue...After login I close the browser and open the browser it goes to the login page again.... It should be in logged in state?
What should be done in order to maintain the login even after the browser is closed and opened again? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You use `logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)`. Maybe you can try to add

`logout().deleteCookies("cookie-names-to-clear")`

maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43774016/6877970) can help