# How to logout user in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logout

I am trying to logout a user in my springboot application but it still log me again
I have referred to this but didn't worked for me  [Spring Security logout does not work - does not clear security context and authenticated user still exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557294/spring-security-logout-does-not-work-does-not-clear-security-context-and-authe)

This is my SecurityMiddleware code

````
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityMiddleware implements WebSecurityConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .anonymous()
                .disable()
                .addFilterAt(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(userRepository), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout().clearAuthentication(true).logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http401ForbiddenEntryPoint());

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/login/**");
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you try with `.deleteCookies("SESSIONID")`?

Comment: How do you verify you're still logged in?